# Any alternative function in python for C's ferror() in I/O

Tags: python

Is there any direct function like `ferror()` in python too or we can implement it using exception handling only?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
  FILE *fp;
  char ch;
  fp=fopen("TRIAL","w");
  while(!feof(fp))
  {
    ch=fgetc(fp);
    if(ferror())
    {
      printf("Error in reading file");
      break;
    }
    else
      printf("%c",ch);
   }
   fclose(fp);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: See [`IOError`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html?highlight=ioerror#exceptions.IOError), maybe [`OSError`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html?highlight=oserror#exceptions.OSError) too.

Comment: Note that from python3.3 the hierarchy of exceptions changed quite a bit, in better. See the [what's new](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-3151). In particular now `OSError` will catch all exceptions related to I/O and you have some new, more specific exceptions, such as `FileExistsError`, `FileNotFoundError` etc, so you don't have to check the `errno` most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Python only uses exceptions for this.  There's no built-in function that you'd use to ask "is this file object broken somehow?"  And there doesn't need to be: just do whatever operation you want, and if it raises an exception, you'll know it.